# What is the eigenvalue for characteristic polynomial $(1+\lambda^2)\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

What is the eigenvalue for characteristic polynomial $(1+\lambda^2)\lambda$?

Is it $0,i,-i$ or $0,i,i$?

Comment: Is $i$ even a root of $(1+\lambda)^2\lambda$...?

Comment: It should be $-1$ and $0$, unless you meant to write $(1+\lambda^2)\lambda$...

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(1+\lambda^2)\lambda$, in order to obtain complex eigenvalues?

Comment: My bad, i just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factorize your characteristic polynomial as $$p(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda+i)(\lambda-i)$$
So, the eigenvalues (roots of the polynomial) are $0,i,-i$